# get client IP for webservice on java 6 embbeded http server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-6

I am implementing web service on java 6 weight light (embbeded) HTTP server [jax-ws-web-services-without-java-ee-containers](http://today.java.net/article/2007/06/29/jax-ws-web-services-without-java-ee-containers) - for testing purposes -

I want to get the client IP for each request.

I tried to declare web service context in my web service class:

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

then use its message context in web method:

```
MessageContext msgx = wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)msgx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());   ---->>> NULLPointerException
```

but, it give me **Null** HTTP request.

I used the same way but with SOAP Handler, but the same problem :((

Is there a way to get it, please??

thanks in advance,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same idea, but with little change:

```
MessageContext msgx = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpExchange exchange = (HttpExchange)msgx.get("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.http.exchange");
    System.out.println(exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress());
```

thanks,,,